# AWS Amplify throws ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 when running nuxt generate

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy my nuxt app via AWS Amplify. Here is my build config:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run generate
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Once it gets to the build part of the deploy, the console gives the following output in the build phase:

```
2021-07-05T18:13:35.839Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2021-07-05T18:13:35.840Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run generate
2021-07-05T18:13:36.003Z [INFO]: > eagle-nuxt@1.0.0 generate /codebuild/output/src824807188/src/eagle-nuxt
                                 > nuxt generate
2021-07-05T18:14:03.863Z [WARNING]: [error]  /articles
                                    connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

I've deployed a nuxt app via amplify before and this is my first time seeing this. Any help would be appreciated

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "core-js": "^3.15.2",
    "marked": "^2.0.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.2"
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue! While developing locally, I was using a .env file. I had to add the environment variable to my build via through amplify. Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#access-env-vars